# which permission should be for client svn folder?(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, svn

which permission should be for client svn folder?(Ubuntu)

the case:

I should download files from svn server to my computer and able to do all svn action as programmer that doing change in the code(update etc..).

Default folder permission enforce working with sudo, Soo i think to change folder permission to 755.

Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default folder permissions are 0755 on Linux.  If you're asking whether or not you should change folder permissions to something other than that, the answer is almost certainly "no."

Update: It sounds like you have an ownership issue based on your comments.  To change ownership to your user and your user's group, use the following:

```
chown -R youruser:youruser /path/to/svn/working/dir
```

So for your case, if your username is `yosef` and you had used `svn co` in `/home/yosef/some_svn_repo_you_checked_out`, your command would be:

```
chown -R yosef:yosef /home/yosef/some_svn_repo_you_checked_out
```

Comment: soo why when i $ mkdir newdir not working? only with sudo?

Comment: Its probably not *owned* by the right user.  Run `ls -l <directory>` and see what user owns it.

Comment: root, I ask about which permission should be for svn client folder

Comment: In your question, you asked about default [folder permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions).  What you're talking about now is ownership, and the question is--if this is indeed the client side, why did you checkout your svn repository as the root user?  I've updated my original answer to get you out of the mess--but it goes without saying that you should NEVER be executing arbitrary commands as root.